# Как сделать ввод массива через textbox C#

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] strArr = new string[]
        {
            textBox1.Text
        };
        textBox2.Text = strArr;
```

При таком способе выводится ошибка - Не удаётся неявно преобразовать тип string[] в string.

Comment: `textBox2.Text = strArr[0];`

Comment: Alexander Petrov, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты пытаешься засунуть **массив strArr** в **переменную** **textBox2.Text**.
если тебе нужен определённый элемент массива то используй

```
textBox2.Text = strArr[номер элемента]
```

если нужно весь массив то(массив условно 10 элементов):

```
for( int i = 0; strArr[i] == 9; i++)
{
textBox2.Text += strArr[i];
}
```